# Google maps - give the coordinates via street address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

guys!

I'm working right now on one of my projects, and can't find the way to add markers in such a way:

I have an array, in which there are coordinates and some else info about these markers.

```
lat = 0; lng = 0;
```

But I'm interested in another way of giving coordinates to the Google.Map, like this one:

`Augsburger Straße, Augsburg, Deutschland`

and it's very interesting if there any way to add markers in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests

e.g.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Augsburger Straße, Augsburg, Deutschland'}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped me :)